# Tile a square as small as possible using two different sizes of square tiles

Tags: optimization, tiling

There are two types of square tiles. One type has a side length of 1 cm and the other has a side length of 2 cm.
What is the smallest square that can be made with equal numbers of each type of tile?

---

This puzzle is from a UK Junior Mathematical Olympiad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is obviously

> an integer.

> If we use $k$ tiles of type 1 (side length 1) and $k$ tiles of type 2 (side length 2), the total area is $5k$, which means the square made this way must be of side length $5x$.

Now consider

> the square of side length 5, which is the smallest of the kind. In order for that to be the answer, we need to put five non-overlapping 2x2 squares into the 5x5 region.

But

> it is impossible by the following coloring argument: every 2x2 square must cover one of the `X`s, but there are only four of them.
>
> ```
> .....
> .X.X.
> .....
> .X.X.
> .....
> ```

Therefore,

> the answer is **10**. A square of side length 10 allows the following tiling of 20 2x2 tiles (marked by lowercase letters) and 20 1x1 tiles (marked by dots):
>
> ```
> aabbccddee
> aabbccddee
> ffgghhiijj
> ffgghhiijj
> kkllmmnnoo
> kkllmmnnoo
> ppqqrrsstt
> ppqqrrsstt
> ..........
> ..........
> ```

Comment: I think some diagonal positioning could perhaps work for similar combinations of squares.